# How can I create an ADFS relying party with an additional SAML endpoint using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, saml, adfs

I want to create an ADFS relying party with an additional SAML endpoint using:

```
$SamlEndpoint = New-AdfsSamlEndpoint `
    -Binding "POST" `
    -Protocol "SAMLSingleSignOn" `
    -Uri "https://$AdditionalUrl/plugins/servlet/samlsso/metadata$SingleLogout"

Add-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust `
    -Name "$Name" `
    -MetadataUrl "https://$AppHost.lab.example.com/plugins/servlet/samlsso/metadata$SingleLogout" `
    -SamlEndpoint $SamlEndpoint `
    -AccessControlPolicyName "Permit Everyone" `
    -MonitoringEnabled $true `
    -AutoUpdateEnabled $true `
    -IssuanceTransformRules $IssuanceRules
```

Without the parameter `-SamlEndpoint ...` the script works fine. With I get the error message:

> Add-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the
>   specified named parameters. At
>   C:\Users\ssh.AD\scripts\addRelyingParty.ps1:34 char:2
>   +     Add-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust `
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.IdentityServer.Management.Commands.AddRelyingPartyTrustCommand

How can I write that?

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here.

First the $SamlEndpoint needs to be a "SAMLAssertionConsumer". SAMLSingleSignOn is for claims provider trusts.

Secondly you are using metadata while adding RP trust and are enabling and monitoring it. So the cmdlet will attempt to download metadata and use its values to define the RP trust properties such as endpoints. You need not provide the endpoint config as its published in metadata.

But if you wanted to add a RP trust as you see fit and then let AD FS monitor and fix via polling metadata I suggest doing it like so.

```
$SamlEndpoint = New-AdfsSamlEndpoint `
-Binding "POST" `
-Protocol "SAMLAssertionConsumer" `
-index 0 -isdefault $false `
-Uri "https://some/post/url/endpoint"

$samlEndpoint2 = New-AdfsSamlEndpoint `
-Binding Redirect `
-Protocol SAMLAssertionConsumer `
-Uri "https://some/redirect/endpoint"`
-Index 1 `
-IsDefault $true


Add-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust `
-Name "$Name" `
-Identifier "http://x/y" `
-SamlEndpoint $SamlEndpoint,$samlendpoint2 `
-AccessControlPolicyName "Permit Everyone" `
-MonitoringEnabled $false `
-AutoUpdateEnabled $false `
-IssuanceTransformRulesFile c:\my\rulesfile.txt

Get-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -Name $name | Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust `
-MetadataUrl "https://$AppHost.lab.example.com/plugins/servlet/samlsso/metadata$SingleLogout"  `
-MonitoringEnabled $true     `
-AutoUpdateEnabled $true
```